# Passing "yielder" objects to Ruby's Enumerator

Tags: ruby

I was going through the documentation for the `Enumerator` class, and found a Fibonacci implementation that confuses me. Here's the code:

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end

p fib.take(10) #=> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

What is going on here? The two lines in the loop block especially confuse me.

Link: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-c-new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation you linked to mentions, `<<` is an alias for the `yield` method on the yielder object so the first line in the loop is equivalent to:

```
y.yield a
```

This is the mechanism by which the `Enumerator` returns its next value when the `next` method is called.

`a, b = b, a + b` is a parallel assignment, assigning the new values to `a` and `b`, but the way this works is that all the values of the expressions on the right hand side are calculated *first* and then assigned to the variables listed on the left hand side so `a` becomes the previous value of `b` and `b` becomes the value of the previous `a + b`, as required to generate the Fibonacci sequence.

What happens when the `Enumerator` is asked for its next value is that the block executes until it reaches the `yield` then the execution of the block stops and that value is returned as the next value. Then when the next value after that is requested the block continues from where it left off (so in this example it will be calculating the new `a` and `b`) and then carries on until it hits the `yield` to return the next value.

Comment: I don't suppose the "yielder" object can be explained? Why have this object at all? Why not just `yield a`?

Comment: @DanielStevens the `yield` keyword e.g. `yield a` is used inside a method body to call (yield control to) the code block supplied as part of the method call, passing any parameters to `yield` as parameters to the block. But this isn't what we need here. If we have have an `Enumerator` and want to use one of the methods from `Enumerable` on it, lets say `find`, then we need a way to pass values from one block (the values generated by `Enumerator.new`'s block) to another block (the block passed to `find`) - this is what the yielder object is for.